# Div width equal with the image child width

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="... .png">
</div>
```

and this CSS rule:

```
.test { background: red; }
```

By default `div`s have `100%` width. Is it possible to set `.test`'s width to the image width that is inside of `.test` only by using CSS?

That means that the red area will be only under the transparent png.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KtS6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `display` property for the container:

```
.test {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/3KtS6/5/

Comment: This is a solution, but isn't there any solution without `inline-block` display? I think that this will break other things in my app...

Comment: Another solution will be using `float` or `display:table`... but can break elements too all depend on the full layout. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/3KtS6/7/ @イオニカビザウ

Comment: Thanks, I think I will set the width via JS.

Answer (score 2):

use `display:inline-block;`

```
.test {
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KtS6/3/

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the background of the `image` to red: http://jsfiddle.net/3KtS6/2/ ?